# Wrong message time difference

Tags: python, time

I have a question regarding a code. I just started a programming course and this is obviously not a very efficient code. It is part of a bigger code but this is where I get a wrong output.

I have a distance in Km, speed in km/h and arrival time (arr) as a list [month, day, hour, min]
I used y = time.time()-1577793600 to get the current time in seconds this year. (the number I'm subtracting is the amount of seconds since Unix epoch time. (I know this is a terrble way of doing it but I thought it somewhat made sense). Also, time_to_destination is the time required to get to the destination in seconds.

```py
import time

distance = 1000

speed = 3

arrival = [10, 13, 11, 30]

y = time.time()-1577793600
time_to_destination = (distance*1000) / (speed / 3.6)

arr = ((arrival[0]-1)*(30*24*3600)+ (arrival[1]-1)*(24*3600) + (arrival[2])*(3600)+(arrival[3]))

ti = arr - time_to_destination
            
if arr < y:
    return 'Date is in the past'
            
elif y > ti:
     return 'You are too late'
```

However, this should return "Your are too late", since the time arrival time isn't in the past but I can't make it with the speed I've given. However, The output is "Date is in the past". Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

The output of your variables are as follows:

```
 ti : 23204430.0
 y  : 24713466.130041838
 arr: 24404430
```

So based on this, the if-else condition will  check the first condition that is `if arr < y`
which should be false to go to the next condition. Since it is getting true in the first condition itself `24713466.130041838 > 24404430`, it's not going to the second condition.
Either you need to select the correct conversion of date to put in the if-else condition or choose appropriate variable

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your variables:
`1577793600` is actually Tuesday, December 31, 2019 12:00:00 PM. Shouldn't that be `1577836800`?

There's also no conversion for the minutes parameter happening. You need to multiply the minutes by 60.

```py
arr = ((arrival[0]-1)*(30*24*3600)+ (arrival[1]-1)*(24*3600) + (arrival[2])*(3600)+(arrival[3]*(60)))
```

Using 30 as number of days per month is also an approximation that can give you false results.

I would really recommend looking into the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll look into it. I know 30 days a month isn't correct, however that's what they used in the exercise. (It's for beginners)